# Redesign json structure to reduce duplication of ids

Tags: clean-code, json

I have json like below in our legacy system. In general, my json is very large. To make things simpler and easier to understand I have reduced the entries.

```
{
    "clientSettings": [{
            "clientId": 12345,
            "key": "abc",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "clientId": 12345,
            "key": "def",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "clientId": 12345,
            "key": "ghi",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "clientId": 9876,
            "key": "lkmn",
            "value": false
        }
    ],
    "clientGroupSettings": [{
            "clientDataId": 11,
            "key": "jkl",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "clientDataId": 11,
            "key": "mno",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "clientDataId": 12,
            "key": "jkl",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "clientDataId": 12,
            "key": "mno",
            "value": true
        }
    ],
    "productSettings": [{
            "configurationDataId": 11,
            "key": "jkl",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "configurationDataId": 11,
            "key": "mno",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "configurationDataId": 12,
            "key": "jkl",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "configurationDataId": 12,
            "key": "mno",
            "value": true
        }
    ],
    "customerSettings": [{
            "key": "enableData",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "key": "minPriceValue",
            "value": "1.0"
        }, {
            "key": "presentData",
            "value": "AEGIS"
        }
    ]
}
```

- In `clientSettings` json array we have `clientId's` and their keys/values. For single `clientId`, I can have multiple different keys and values. For example - `12345` `clientId` has different keys and values as shown below.
- Similarly it's the same thing for `clientGroupSettings` as well.
- And same for `productSettings` as well.
- But for `customerSettings` I just have different keys and values.

I am thinking to redesign the above json so that I don't have to duplicate `clientId`, `clientDataId` and `configurationDataId` for each key and values where they are same. As of now my json is huge because I have lot of `ids` which are same but with different keys and values.

What's the best way to reorganize this so that I don't have to duplicate `clientId`, `clientDataId` and `configurationDataId`?

I am more interested in re-designing `clientSettings`, `clientGroupSettings` and `productSettings` json array.

Comment: There is no best way. It depends what you need to do with it. What have. you tried?

Comment: I just want to make sure we don't duplicate `clientId`, `clientDataId` and `configurationDataId` for each key and values. I was thinking to make json array for each of those ids?

Comment: Why do you have `{"key": "jkl", "value": true}, {"key": "mno", "value": true}`, etc. instead of `{"jkl": true, "mno": true}`?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to organize JSON. Here are two...

**1. Array of clientId objects each containing an array of entries**

```
{
  "clientSettings": [
    {
        "clientId": 12345,
        "entries": [
             {"key": "abc", "value": false},
             {"key": "def","value": false},
             {"key": "ghi","value": false}
        ]
    },
    {
        "clientId": 9876,
        "entries": [
             {"key": "lkmn", "value": false}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. Object Keyed by clientId, containing object Keyed by your "key" property.**

```
{
    "clientSettings": {
        "12345":
            {
                "abc": false,
                 "def": false,
                 "ghi": false
            },
        "9876": {
                 "lkmn": false
            }
    }
}
```

**Which is better?**

It depends on your needs, and to some degree on the tools you use.

- The second form guarantees that a clientId will not appear twice and a key will not. appear twice for a clientId.
- The first form documents what the clientId and other fields are.

Ease of use depends a lot on toolset and developer proficiency.

For example, in Javascript and Java they are equally easy to navigate.
In Java they are equally easy to deserialize into Collections/Map classes or your own named classes, if you are proficient with a good JSON serializer like Jackson or GSON.

Deciding which is better, or whether some other is better depends on having some criteria. Compactness? Self-Documenting? Enforces cardinality rules? Contains type info for deserializing? Etc.